# EJB annotation doesnt work in JSF

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

i'm starting with JEE and i need to work with JSF-EJB-JPA.

I have an EJB project and it deploys ok, my war file too. When i use the annotation EJB to in a properti in the war, it simply doesnt work, no information is show

I have an h:dataTable and i want to populate it with info that comes from a database, injeting an EJB, but the data just not show (i dont know if it didnt arrive to the WAR or only it isnt being showed). The table is empty, only with the headers that i (of course) wrote directly.

if i dont use @EJB anywhere, the data that doesnt come from the EJB is showed correctly, for example, if i write "Hello world" i cant print it in , but when i dare to use @EJB even that information stop working, as if using  @EJB broke all the conection between the xhtml and the manager.

i followed a tutorial, and in the video everything went good.

a part of the controller:

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.ejb.EJB;

@Named(value = "editorialController")
@SessionScoped
public class EditorialController implements Serializable {

    @EJB//(name=Tutorial-ejb")
    private EditorialFacade editorialFacade;
    private Integer randomInt;

    public List<Editorial> findAll()
    {
        return this.editorialFacade.findAll();
    }

    public Integer getRandomInt() {
        return randomInt;
    }

    public void setRandomInt(Integer randomInt) {
        this.randomInt = randomInt;
    }
}
```

a pice of the xhtml

```
<h:body>
Hello from Facelets
<h:outputLabel value="#{editorialController.randomInt}"></h:outputLabel>
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable var="p" value="#{editorialController.findAll()}">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="Header">
                <h:outputText value="NAME"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{p.nombre}"></h:outputText>
         </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
</h:body>
```

i tried with: #{editorialController.findAll()} and #{editorialController.findAll}

For the EJB, are as usual: a package for entities, other for facades; netbeans generated them, so i think its not necesary copy&paste the code.
im using glassfish (payara). web.xml has all the JSF stuff.

the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Tutorial-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
       <jta-data-source>jdbc/MyDataSource</jta-data-source> 
       <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
       <properties>
          <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
       </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Comment: rename `findAll()` to `getEditorials()` and link it in this way `value="#{editorialController.editorils}"`. EL uses bean like properties to communicate with the managed beans. and place the bean into request/view scope if it doesn't store data for other views.

Comment: if it does not work, log the count of the list in the `findAll()`/`getEditorials` method. if it is logs 0, then the error in the injected bean method.

Comment: @TheBitman: **don't do any work in getters** or do it lazy. Search google on 'why does jsf call a getter multiple times'

Comment: @Kukeltje you are right. it can be a getter method to a derived attribute (or lazy fetched one depending on a tech dialect :) )

Comment: what tutorial are you following? It is not a good one, See my previous comment. And do some basic debugging what is retrieved and what not in which methods